# Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps)

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I scaffolded Yesod project using `yesod init && cd lemonstand`. When I do "cabal install", it throws the error,

```
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).
```

Then i passed an option as `max-backjumps`,

```
cabal install --max-backjumps 100
```

And i followed the [reddit conversation](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2ameew/best_practices_for_avoiding_cabal_hell/), and did this,

```
cabal install --max-backjumps 100 --reorder-goals
```

None of these steps worked. Any clues?

Answer (score 5):

100 is too low a backjump count. I typically recommend `--max-backjumps=-1` to set it to an unbounded number. However, a more robust way of installing Yesod is to use LTS Haskell, so that the dependency tree is solved and tested for you by the Stackage project. This is the approach taken by [the Yesod quickstart guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart). Typically, this can be achieved by running the following inside your project directory:

```
wget https://www.stackage.org/lts/cabal.config
```

This will require that you're using GHC 7.8.X, preferably 7.8.4.